# Executing multiple functions/commands on Arduino

Tags: led

I am using an [RFduino](http://www.rfduino.com/) and an iOS application to control some RGB LEDs.

This is how I'm sending a string command to the module:

```
- (IBAction)fadeButtonPressed:(id)sender {
    [rfduino send:[@"fade" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
}
```

These command(s) are coming back just fine on the RFduino side:

```
void RFduinoBLE_onReceive(char *data, int len) {
  if (strncmp(data, "fade", 4) == 0) {
    // begin fading chosen LED colour
  }
}
```

Is there a better way of executing multiple functions on Arduino? It seems to me that there should be a better way of doing what I'm trying to do.

Originally for example I was getting an issue where the "fade" string was coming back as "fadek" so I used `strncmp(data, "fade", 4)` instead of `strcmp(data, "fade")` and this fixed the issue.

I guess I'd like a way of cleaning up my code and perhaps make it easier to introduce new bits of functionality depending on which strings are coming back.

The functions I would like to be able to do would be controlling of the RGB colours and then *Fading* or *Blinking* that particular chosen colour.

What if I wanted to introduce faster blinking? Rather than setting another command integer and adding another condition is there a cleaner approach?

The selection of the colours is set by selection of a color wheel within my iOS application. This is working fine. The problem is that the Blinking and Fading does not blink/fade the selected colour (`command 0`).

Here is my entire sketch so far:

```
#include <RFduinoBLE.h>

// Pin 2 on the RGB LED.
int rgb2_pin = 2; // red
int rgb3_pin = 3; // green
int rgb4_pin = 4; // blue
int brightness = 0;
int fadeAmount = 5;

// Command properties.
int command = 0;

void setup() {
  // debug output at 9600 baud
  Serial.begin(9600);

  // Setup the LEDs for output.
  pinMode(rgb2_pin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(rgb3_pin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(rgb4_pin, OUTPUT);

  // This is the data we want to appear in the advertisement
  // (the deviceName length plus the advertisement length must be <= 18 bytes.
  RFduinoBLE.advertisementData = "rgb";

  // Start the BLE stack.
  RFduinoBLE.begin();
}

void loop() {
  if (command == 1) { // Fade in/out chosen colour.
    analogWrite(rgb2_pin, brightness);
    analogWrite(rgb3_pin, brightness);
    analogWrite(rgb4_pin, brightness);

    // Change the brightness for next time through the loop:
    brightness = brightness + fadeAmount;

    // Reverse the direction of the fading at the ends of the fade:
    if (brightness == 0 || brightness == 255) {
      fadeAmount = -fadeAmount ;
    }

    // Wait for 30 milliseconds to see the dimming effect
    delay(30);
  } else if (command == 2) { // Blink
    digitalWrite(rgb2_pin, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(rgb3_pin, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(rgb4_pin, HIGH);
    delay(200);
    digitalWrite(rgb2_pin, LOW);
    digitalWrite(rgb3_pin, LOW);
    digitalWrite(rgb4_pin, LOW);
    delay(200);
  }
}

void RFduinoBLE_onConnect() {}

void RFduinoBLE_onDisconnect() {}

void RFduinoBLE_onReceive(char *data, int len) {
  Serial.println(data);

  // Each transmission should contain an RGB triple.
  if (strncmp(data, "fade", 4) == 0) {
    command = 1;
  } else if (strncmp(data, "blink", 5) == 0) {
    command = 2;
  } else { // Change colour.
    // Reset other functions.
    command = 0;

    if (len >= 3) {
      // Get the RGB values.
      uint8_t red = data[0];
      uint8_t green = data[1];
      uint8_t blue = data[2];

      // Set PWM for each LED.
      analogWrite(rgb2_pin, red);
      analogWrite(rgb3_pin, green);
      analogWrite(rgb4_pin, blue);
    }
  }

  Serial.println(command);
}
```

Comment: +1 for the way you've posted your question. I hate it when people don't write comments in their script. But you did write comments!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ended up going with something [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24005992/arduino-state-machine):

```
#include <RFduinoBLE.h>

// State properties.
int state = 1;
char command;
String hexstring;

// RGB pins.
int redPin = 2;
int grnPin = 3;
int bluPin = 4;

// Setup function to set RGB pins to OUTPUT pins.
void setup () {
  pinMode(redPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(grnPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(bluPin, OUTPUT);

  // This is the data we want to appear in the advertisement
  // (the deviceName length plus the advertisement length must be <= 18 bytes.
  RFduinoBLE.deviceName = "iOS";
  RFduinoBLE.advertisementInterval = MILLISECONDS(300);
  RFduinoBLE.txPowerLevel = -20;
  RFduinoBLE.advertisementData = "rgb";

  // Start the BLE stack.
  RFduinoBLE.begin();
}

void loop () {
  switch (command) {
    case 1:
      // Blink.
    break;
    case 2:
      // Fade.
    break;
  }

  //RFduino_ULPDelay(INFINITE);
}

// Converts HEX as a String to actual HEX values.
// This is needed to properly convert the ASCII value to the hex
// value of each character.
byte getVal (char c) {
  if (c >= '0' && c <= '9') return (byte)(c - '0');
  else return (byte)(c - 'a' + 10);
}

// Process each function/command.
void processCommand (int command, String hex) {
  switch (command) {
    case 'b':
      command = 1; // Set blink mode.
    break;
    case 'f':
      command = 2; // Set fade mode.
    break;
    case 'c':
      // We put together 2 characters as is
      // done with HEX notation and set the color.
      byte red = getVal(hex.charAt(1)) + (getVal(hex.charAt(0)) << 4);
      byte green = getVal(hex.charAt(3)) + (getVal(hex.charAt(2)) << 4);
      byte blue = getVal(hex.charAt(5)) + (getVal(hex.charAt(4)) << 4);

      // Set the color.
      setColor (red, green, blue);
    break;
  }
}

// Sets the color of each RGB pin.
void setColor (byte red, byte green, byte blue) {
  analogWrite(redPin, red);
  analogWrite(grnPin, green);
  analogWrite(bluPin, blue);
  delay(200);
}

// This function returns data from the radio.
void RFduinoBLE_onReceive (char *data, int len) {
  for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    stateMachine(data[i]);
  }
}

// Main state machine function, which processes
// data depending on the bytes received.
void stateMachine (char data) {
  switch (state) {
    case 1:
      if (data == 1) {
        state = 2;
      }
    break;
    case 2:
      if (data == 'b' || data == 'f' || data == 'c') {
        command = data;
        hexstring = "";
        state = 3;
      } else if (data != 1) { // Stay in state 2 if we received another 0x01.
        state = 1;
      }
    break;
    case 3:
      if ((data >= 'a' && data <= 'z') || (data >= '0' && data <= '9')) {
        hexstring = hexstring + data;
        if (hexstring.length() == 6) {
          state = 4;
        }
      } else if (data == 1) {
        state = 2;
      } else {
        state = 1;
      }
    break;
    case 4:
      if (data == 3) {
        processCommand(command, hexstring);
        state = 1;
      } else if (data == 1) {
        state = 2;
      } else {
        state = 1;
      }
    break;
  }
}
```

Comment: Does the delay(), millis() etc. work on the RFduino?

Comment: @Phataas: Not sure, why?

Comment: I saw you removed them.

Comment: @Phataas: Oh, I just noticed that. I'll add them back in after the `analogWrite()` calls.